# Can I travel to Norway without a visa?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, visa-free-entry, norway, italian-residents

I have an Italian residence permit with a Pakistani passport. Can I travel to Norway without a visa?

Comment: Why are you asking so many questions with same body different country? It looks like you are considering Italian visa to be a privilege card for rest of the world

Comment: Hahaha Because i wanna know that what is the power of my schengean residency in the world where i can travel for visa free

Comment: It lets you work in Italy. No power games involved.

Comment: Yeah i am doing . But my wishess i do travel to the world so i do planing for my holidays

Comment: @HankyPanky It gives a visa exemption for many places

Comment: @ZaheerBahi Wrote an answer :)

Comment: @Coke see all the questions asked today by the OP

Comment: Norway is in the Schengen area.  So is Italy.  So yes: because you live in the Schengen area, you can travel to other countries in the Schengen area.

Comment: Do you have "Permesso di soggiorno"?

Answer (score 2):

You can visit Norway.

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 90 days

With your passport and Italian residence permit, you can visit Schengen countries, Croatia, Bosnia, Serbia, Montenegro, Albania, Kosovo, Romania, Bulgaria and Cyprus, Georgia, French overseas territories and the Dominican Republic.

If having a **permanent** residence permit, you can also enter Macedonia, Turkey (at Istanbul-Atatürk or Ankara Airport) and Mexico

Comment: @HankyPanky Either a visa or permanent residence Permit. A temporary residence Permit will **not** do.

Comment: Which is one of the most bizarre rules in the world, and only makes sense if the people making the rule weren't paying attention to the meaning of the terms *visa, residence permit,* and *permanent residence permit.*

Comment: @phoog I disagree with it too, but it remains the law, and if trying to "improvise" it, you can't be guaranteed to be allowed on a plane or not to be deported on arrival. Albania also allows citizens of Australia, New Zealand, Hong Kong and Singapore to enter with a national ID card. Australia and New Zealand don't have anything of the sort, while Hong Kong and Singapore's IDs aren't tied to citizenship, but residency. Bizarre? Yes! But it's still the law